# How to replicate the GA4 User Engagement value with Bigquery export

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am running the following query off of daily GA4 exported data in Bigquery, to replicate the User Engagement value from the GA4 API

```sql
SELECT
  SUM((
    SELECT
      value.int_value/1000
    FROM
      UNNEST(event_params)
    WHERE
      KEY = 'engagement_time_msec'))
FROM
  `BI_1.analytics_331127371.events_*`
where _TABLE_SUFFIX between '20230301' AND '20230315'
```

I am getting values 3% higher than what the API shows. According to the google doc here https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11109416#user-engagement Google uses the engagement_time_msec to calculate User engagement.

Answer (score 1):

Don't expect the Reports to coincide with BQ. In fact, 3% difference is quite an achievement.

Keep in mind that GA4 Reports are based on sampled and pre-aggregated data rather than the raw data. If you want to compare things between GA4 and BQ, you have to use the Explore view and build dashboards there. Pre-baked GA4 reports don't really bring much value. They're now more meant as vanity reports for people not very familiar with data analysis.

Comment: I'm getting my values directly from the API not the pre made dashboard reports in the UI. Is it expected to have a several % difference between direct API values and BQ?

Comment: no, direct API requests should be equivalent to BQ. Moreover, most of the ETL experts no longer bother with the reporting API since it's convoluted and very easy to make an error, so they end up just ETLing the data from BQ. Why do you have the 3% difference? You'd have to dig. Maybe even into how reliable the Reporting API is for GA4. There were talks about it still being raw.